# Inheritance and aggregation UML

Tags: java, c++, inheritance, uml, aggregation

Would like to know if the UML is reasonable and acceptable?

Please do not question the need for composition or aggregation based on the names of the classes.

Just treat them as they are as shown on the UML.

Also, I am actually using GoodArticle to communicate with Newspaper and not the parent class Article in actual coding. But in terms of representing UML, I should still connect the parent class (Article) to newspaper even though it is actually GoodArticle?

This is also arguably similar to the case where GoodArticle connects with BadArticle for composition. Should BadArticle connect to parent class Article instead? However I am actually using GoodArticle to connect with BadArticle in coding.

[image: Inheritance and aggregation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will read your diagram as it is, that is - I will interpret it. If my interpretation is correct, than your model is likely to be correct. That's what the UML is all about - transmit unambiguously information under modelling.

So...

- Reading the diagram: Newspaper has Articles, both GoodArticles and BadArticles. Articles exist independently on the Newspaper and if you for example delete a Newspaper instance, its Articles will remain "floating" around. You say:

> I am actually using GoodArticle to communicate with Newspaper and not
>   the parent class Article in actual coding. But in terms of
>   representing UML, I should still connect the parent class (Article) to
>   newspaper even though it is actually GoodArticle?

No. If only GoodArticles are connected to Newspaper, that you should draw it between those two classes. This kind of class diagram is a blueprint of code and should show the code structure preciselly.

- Reading the diagram: GoodArticle contains BadArticles. This containment is exclusive, meaning that if GoodArticle is deleted, all contained BadArticles will automatically be deleted.

Here you say:

> Should BadArticle connect to parent class Article instead? However I
>   am actually using GoodArticle to connect with BadArticle in coding.

This time the diagram reflects the code, so it is ok, BadArticle should not be connected to Article. If you do it, that would mean that also BadArticle can can contain other BadArticles.

Note that the attribute listOfBadArticle is probably redundant. If it refers to the composition on the diagram, you should just remove it and use it as a name on the corresponding composition end.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't quite understand your last paragraph about listOfBadArticle. It is not redundant as this was a necessary implementation on a question. Hence, I prefer Composition over aggregation for this relationship to answer the question. Also, while I agree that GoodArticle should be connected to newspaper directly, I cant seem to find such diagrams of similar cases around.